# Data is not inserted to 3rd table in many to many relation in doctrine 2.4 and CodeIgniter 2.2

Tags: doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

This question is asked many times on stackoverflow, but none of them helped me.

I have 3 tables:

- `student`
- `subject`
- `student_subject`

**Problem:** When I try to insert the data, rows are inserted into `student` and `subject` tables, but NOT into `student_subject` table.

**Detailes on environment:**

- CodeIginter 2.2
- Doctrine 2.4
- Xampp
- PHP 5.5.15
- Apache 2.4.4
- mysql 5.0.11
- Windows 8.1 x64 pro

**Detailes on database schema:** My table structures are:

- `student_subject` table:

  ```
  mysql> desc student_subject;
  +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | student_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
  | subject_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
  +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
  ```
- `subject` table:

  ```
  mysql> desc student;
  +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  | class | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
  ```
- `subject` table:

  ```
  mysql> desc subject;
  +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  | name   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  | author | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  +--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
  ```

**Detailes on PHP (CodeIgniter) code:**

- `C:\xampp\htdocs\test_orm\application\libraries\doctrine.php`:

  ```
  <?php
  use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
      Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
      Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
      Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
      Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger,
      Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver,
      Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory,
      Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator;

  /**
   * CodeIgniter Smarty Class
   *
   * initializes basic doctrine settings and act as doctrine object
   *
   * @final       Doctrine
   * @category    Libraries
   */
  class Doctrine {

    /**
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
      public $em = null;

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
      // load database configuration from CodeIgniter
      require APPPATH.'config/database.php';

      // Set up class loading. You could use different autoloaders, provided by your favorite framework,
      // if you want to.
      require_once APPPATH.'third_party/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

      $doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine',  APPPATH.'third_party');
      $doctrineClassLoader->register();
      $entitiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('models', rtrim(APPPATH, "/" ));
      $entitiesClassLoader->register();
      $proxiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('proxies', APPPATH.'models');
      $proxiesClassLoader->register();

      // Set up caches
      $config = new Configuration;
      $cache = new ArrayCache;
      $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
      $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(APPPATH.'models/Entities'));
      $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
      $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

      // Proxy configuration
      $config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'models/proxies');
      $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

      // Set up logger
      //$logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
      //$config->setSQLLogger($logger);

      $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE );  
      // Database connection information
      $connectionOptions = array(
          'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
          'user' =>     $db['default']['username'],
          'password' => $db['default']['password'],
          'host' =>     $db['default']['hostname'],
          'dbname' =>   $db['default']['database']
      );

      // Create EntityManager
      $this->em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);  

          $this->em->getConfiguration()
                  ->setMetadataDriverImpl(
                      new DatabaseDriver(
                              $this->em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
                      )
          );

      //$this->generate_classes(); 
      }
      /**
       * generate entity objects automatically from mysql db tables
       * @return none
       */
      function generate_classes(){    


          $cmf = new DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
          $cmf->setEntityManager($this->em);
          $metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();    
          $generator = new EntityGenerator();

          $generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
          $generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
          $generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
          $generator->generate($metadata, APPPATH."models/Entities");

      }

  }
  ```
- `C:\xampp\htdocs\test_orm\application\models\Entities\Subject.php`

  ```
  <?php



  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

  /**
   * Subject
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="subject")
   * @ORM\Entity
   */
  class Subject
  {

      public function __construct() {
          $this->students = new ArrayCollection();
      }

      /**
       * @var integer
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
       */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @var string
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
       */
      private $name;

      /**
       * @var string
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
       */
      private $author;


      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Student" mappedBy="subjects")
       */
      protected $students;

      /**
       * Get id
       *
       * @return integer 
       */
      public function getId()
      {
          return $this->id;
      }

      /**
       * Set name
       *
       * @param string $name
       * @return Subject
       */
      public function setName($name)
      {
          $this->name = $name;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * Get name
       *
       * @return string 
       */
      public function getName()
      {
          return $this->name;
      }

      /**
       * Set author
       *
       * @param string $author
       * @return Subject
       */
      public function setAuthor($author)
      {
          $this->author = $author;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * Get author
       *
       * @return string 
       */
      public function getAuthor()
      {
          return $this->author;
      }

      /**
       * Add the Student to Subject
       *
       * @param Student $student
       * @return void
       */
      public function addStudent(Student $student){
          $student->addSubject($this);
          $this->students[] =$student;
      }

      public function getStudents () {
          return $this->students;
      }
  }
  ```
- `C:\xampp\htdocs\test_orm\application\models\Entities\Student.php`

  ```
  <?php

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

  /**
   * Student
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="student")
   * @ORM\Entity
   */
  class Student
  {

      public function __construct() {
          $this->subjects = new ArrayCollection();
      }

      /**
       * @var integer
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
       */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @var string
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
       */
      private $name;

      /**
       * @var string
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="class", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
       */
      private $class;

      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Subject", inversedBy="students")
       * @ORM\JoinTable(name="student_subject")    
       */
      protected $subjects;

      /**
       * Get id
       *
       * @return integer 
       */
      public function getId()
      {
          return $this->id;
      }

      /**
       * Set name
       *
       * @param string $name
       * @return Student
       */
      public function setName($name)
      {
          $this->name = $name;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * Get name
       *
       * @return string 
       */
      public function getName()
      {
          return $this->name;
      }

      /**
       * Set class
       *
       * @param string $class
       * @return Student
       */
      public function setClass($class)
      {
          $this->class = $class;

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * Get class
       *
       * @return string 
       */
      public function getClass()
      {
          return $this->class;
      }

      /**
       * Add the Subject to Student
       *
       * @param Subject $subject
       * @return void
       */
      public function addSubject(Subject $subject){
          //$subject->addStudent($this);
          $this->subjects[] = $subject;
      }

      public function getSubjects () {
          return $this->subjects;
      }
  }
  ```
- `C:\xampp\htdocs\test_orm\application\models\StudentModel.php`

  ```
  <?php
  require_once(APPPATH."models/Entities/Student.php");
  require_once(APPPATH."models/Entities/Subject.php");
  //use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
  use \Student;
  use \Subject;

  class StudentModel extends CI_Model {

      /**    
       * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
       */
      var $em;

      public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->em = $this->doctrine->em;
      }

      /**
       * Add contact messages to database
       * @param array $contact_form
       * @return bool
       */
      public function addSubject()
      {   
          /**
           * @var Student $student
           */
          $student = new Student();
          $student->setName("Musa Haidari");
          $student->setClass("BCS");

          $subject = new Subject();
          $subject->setName("JAVA");
          $subject->setAuthor("XXX");
          $this->em->persist($subject);

          $subject = new Subject();
          $subject->setName("PHP");
          $subject->setAuthor("YYY");
          $this->em->persist($subject);

          $student->addSubject($subject);        
          $this->em->persist($student);

          try {
              //save to database
              $this->em->flush();
          }
          catch(Exception $err){

              die($err->getMessage());
          }
          return true;       
      }
  }
  ```

  - `C:\xampp\htdocs\test_orm\application\controllers\Landing.php`

    class Landing extends CI_Controller {

    ```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function addStudentSubjectLog () {
        $this->load->model('StudentModel');

        $this->StudentModel->addSubject();

        echo "<br /><br />Done!<br /><br />";
    }
    ```

    }

To insert the data, I enter this URL in the browser:

`http://localhost/test_orm/Landing/addStudentSubjectLog`

Comment: You are not persisting your second `$subject` in `addSubject()`.

Comment: @andy Thank you for interest, however, I have tried that also, but it did not work.

Comment: The [example](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association) manually adds the backwards reference. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Have you validated your mappings & schema? `vendor/bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema`

Comment: Although I don't think this is the source of your issue, the join-table should contain only 2 columns (foreign keys) which together form a composite primary key. Have a look at the output of `vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should uncomment the line `//$subject->addStudent($this);` from the `addSubject` function at your `Student` entity.

Also, remove the line `$student->addSubject($this);` from the `addStudent` function at you `Subject` entity.

I think you should also persist the `$student` object before adding the `$subject` to it. Basically switching these two lines:

```
$student->addSubject($subject);
$this->em->persist($student);
```

Hope this helps.